# Docker not running/showing long-running processes

Tags: docker

Why does this occur?

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
# stuff...
$ docker run ubuntu apt-get install -y tree
Reading package lists...
$
```

It *appears* to die. `$?` is 0 though. I have a similar issue with ping:

```
$ docker run ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=61 time=24.2 ms
^C
 $
```

Note that ping doesn't dump its usual information about lost packets on ^C.

Leaving the ping on for a few minutes doesn't result in a sudden dump of text (like I expect when a buffer is flushed).

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Case with `ping` works fine for me (ubuntu 13.10, Docker version 0.9.1, build 3600720):

```
$ sudo docker run ubuntu ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.32.166) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.32.166: icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=19.1 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.073/19.116/19.159/0.043 ms
```

You can try to run container in interactive mode

```
sudo docker run -i -t  ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and play around with `ping` and `apt-get` there.
Maybe apt-get is just executing some long running process (updating packages list). So you can run it in background and inspect what exactly `apt-get` is doing with top, htop, etc.